# Using MouseDragElementBehavior with an ItemsControl and Canvas

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, attachedbehaviors

I am currently having a problem using the MouseDragElementsBehavior from the Blend SDK when using a ItemsControl and a Custom Canvas.  My custom canvas simply adds or removes the MouseDragElement from its children depending on a DependencyProperty.  This worked just fine when I was manually adding Items to the Canvas' children but appears to have broken when moving to an ItemsControl.

I am currently using the following ItemsControl code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CanvasItems}">
  <ItemsControl.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:ViewModel/>
  </ItemsControl.DataContext>
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <my:CustomCanvas Background="Black" IsEditable="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.CanEdit}" AllowDrop="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEditable}"  />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Adding the Drag Behavior in the Canvas.VisualChildrenChanged method does not allow the newly created object to be moved like before.

Do I need to add the Drag behavior to something other then the ContentPresenter that is passed to VisualChildrenChanged or provide a special style?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the blend sdk behaviours, but I've worked with behaviours in general, so I hope the same mechanisms apply.

If you want to add a behaviour to the controls created by an ItemsControl the best way is adding it via a setter in the ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle, though in this case I found it easier to add it in the ItemsControl.ItemTemplate

Something like

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CanvasItems}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Background="Transparent" AllowDrop="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1" Background="AntiqueWhite">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <ei:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="True" DragBegun="MouseDragElementBehavior_DragBegun"/>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: This would work if I was doing a Drag/Drop (already implmented)...DragMouseElement is used for moving the object around in its container.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I don't have Blend, so I can't test the code. But I still would assume, that MouseDragElementBehaviour would modify the Canvas.X attached Property of the Control it was attached to, so it still should work. The Item Container Style is applied to all Containers generated by the ItemsControl. I've edited the code to reflect the samples of blend behaviours I've seen.

Comment: The style you provided is resulting in a Parameter count mismatch error. Do you happen to remember where you saw these samples so that I may take a look?

Comment: The Sample was http://www.intertech.com/Blog/post/Blend-Behaviors-Are-Good.aspx, but it isn't really helpful for your problem. I had a syntax error in my Code, the tags should be Setter.Value, no just Value. I corrected it. Could you post the Code of your Canvas.VisualChildrenChanged so I can better understand how the behavior works?

Comment: Just downloaded the blend sdk and saw, that Interaction.Behaviors is a readonly, so my solution still won't work. I'll try to find another solution

Comment: I dropped the ItemsContainerStyle completele and now used the ItemTemplate. It lacks a bit of elegance and is more verbose, but it seems to work. I'm still not completely sure how it *should* behave, but at least I reach the DragBegun Event handler as soon as I started dragging the Border. From there you can maipulate the Canvas.X attached property of the sender or something. If you don't want the Border and your Items already have an opaque, draggable form just move the behavior from the border to the ContentControl

Answer (score -1):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CanvasItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="YourControl">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="YourControl">
                        <Border>
                            <Grid>
                                <SystemWindowsInteractivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <MicrosoftExpressionInteractivityLayout:MouseDragElementBehavior />
                                </SystemWindowsInteractivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```