# itemscontrol mouseDragElementbehavior for new items not working

Tags: wpf

I found this solution [Using MouseDragElementBehavior with an ItemsControl and Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358774/using-mousedragelementbehavior-with-an-itemscontrol-and-canvas) by Jörg Reichardt. But it doesn't work for me.

This is my code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CardCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="White" AllowDrop="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <is:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="True" />
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The items are shown on the canvas but cannot be dragged or dropped. I create new items for the cardCollection in the viewmodel and the cardCollection is updated to the model via mvvm propertynotifychanged.